# How to create form modal pop up

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtX6T.png)

I am trying to create a pop up with the add button so the form can display in a modal pop up right now the form is displaying already but I want it to display once  i click the add button is there a way I can fix this

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="mycrud.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <title>My Movies</title>
      <header>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
      </header>
    <button id = "showMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal"
    data-target=#exampleModal>All Movies</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class = "modal-body">
    <form id="newForm">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="idmovielist" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">idmovielist</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intNum" placeholder="idmovielist">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="thumnail_path" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">thumnail_path</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thumnail_path" placeholder="thumnail_path">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="year_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">year_released</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year_released" placeholder="year_released">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="language_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">language_released</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="language_released" placeholder="language_released">
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <button id = "movieAdded" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target=#exampleModal>Add</button>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
      <thead style="background-color:#ddd;" class="table-borderless">
        <tr>
          <th>idmovielist</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>thumnail_path</th>
          <th>description</th>
          <th>year_released</th>
          <th>language_released</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="movies">
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my html code I have a form code and a modal code from bootstrap where can I place the modal code so that this form I have can be a pop up. Basically I am creating a pop up form and if I need to add anything else to help you guys answer the question please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `modal-body` class is outside the modal. to fix that problem, put your `<div class="modal-body"></div>` inside the modal.

I changed your code. please see..

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="mycrud.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <title>My Movies</title>
  <header>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
  </header>
<button id = "showMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal"
data-target=#exampleModal>All Movies</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class = "modal-body">
<form id="newForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="idmovielist" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">idmovielist</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intNum" placeholder="idmovielist">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="thumnail_path" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">thumnail_path</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thumnail_path" placeholder="thumnail_path">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="year_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">year_released</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year_released" placeholder="year_released">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="language_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">language_released</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="language_released" placeholder="language_released">
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<button id = "movieAdded" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
data-target=#exampleModal>Add</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
  <thead style="background-color:#ddd;" class="table-borderless">
    <tr>
      <th>idmovielist</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>thumnail_path</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>year_released</th>
      <th>language_released</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="movies">
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```